# Table join - return all records if one table does not have corrsponding record

Tags: mysql, sql

wI have a join query where I want to return all records even if `specimen_image_lookup.specimen_fk` doesn't have a corresponding record for `specimen.specimen_pk`:

```
SELECT * FROM specimen, topography_index, morphology, specimen_image_lookup, image 
WHERE 
SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code 
AND 
morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code 
AND 
specimen_image_lookup.specimen_fk = specimen.specimen_pk AND image.image_pk = specimen_image_lookup.image_fk 
AND 
topography_index.topography_index_code IN('".implode("','",$sub_cat)."') 
GROUP BY 
specimen.specimen_pk
```

How can I modify this query to return all records even when specimen_image_lookup doesn't have a record for specimen.specimen_pk?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Learn about `left outer join`.

Comment: I guess that is what I'm asking here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an outer join to that table, and also the image table, because you have a join between the image table and that table, which you're saying might not have a related record:

```
select *
  from specimen
  join topography_index
    on substring(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) =
       topography_index.topography_index_code
  join morphology
    on morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code
  left join specimen_image_lookup
    on specimen_image_lookup.specimen_fk = specimen.specimen_pk
  left join image
    on image.image_pk = specimen_image_lookup.image_fk
 where topography_index.topography_index_code in ('".implode("', '",$sub_cat)."')
```

Also it is a good idea in general to use the join clause for all join conditions.

I removed your GROUP BY clause because you have no aggregate functions in the SELECT list and is bad syntax, in any database other than MySQL it would return an error. You only use the GROUP BY clause if you are aggregating something.

Comment: The reason I used a GROUP BY is because some specimens have more than one image, and in this case I just want to get the specimen record, not duplicate the record list if there is more than one image for a specimen.

Comment: You should reduce it using DISTINCT and by chopping off the image columns if you don't need them in the output. As written, the GROUP BY is actually a syntax error, MySQL is the only database that will ignore the error and return an arbitrary single row for each "specimen.specimen_pk" value.